# Problem with SwiftUI Bound to Struct Data

Tags: swiftui

I have 2 text boxes and 1 toggle button bound to Contact: `contact.name`, `contact.enabled`, and `contact.memo`.

Contact has custom implementations of Equatable, etc.

`contact.name` is used in the equatable implementation and updates just fine.

However, `contact.enabled` and `contact.memo` don't update as expected.

If I remove `static func ==`so it auto generates equitable conformance (checking all values), then all updates happen as expected in SwiftUI, however, this isn't viable because equitable needs to work as written and not take into account other parameters.

Here's the data model:

```
struct AppData : Codable {
    var contacts: [Contact] = []
}

struct Contact {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = "New Contact"
    var userModificationDate: Date = Date.distantPast
    var memo: String = "Memo here"
    var enabled: Bool = true
}
extension Contact : Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable, Sendable, Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
        lhs.name == rhs.name &&
        lhs.userModificationDate == rhs.userModificationDate 
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
        hasher.combine(self.name)
        hasher.combine(self.userModificationDate)
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name.localizedCompare(rhs.name) == .orderedAscending
    }
}
```

Here's a test view:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var appData: AppData
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            List() {
                ForEach($appData.contacts) { $contact in
                    HStack {
                        // Updates Fine:
                        TextField("Name", text: $contact.name)
                        // Won't update as expected... can't edit memo text or toggle enabled 
                        Toggle("Enabled", isOn: $contact.enabled).labelsHidden()
                        TextField("Memo", text: $contact.memo)
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                let contact = Contact(userModificationDate: .now)
                appData.contacts.append(contact)
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
            .padding(20)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView(appData: AppData())
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "because equitable needs to work as written and not take into account other parameters." And why is *that*? You can probably create a wrapper around `Contact` and use that for when you need that particular `Equatable` implementation. Or do it the other way round, use the wrapper in SwiftUI code.

Comment: SwiftUI depends on Equatable, if you have to use that version of Equatable you'll have to create a wrapper or some other version of a lot of code to make up for that.

Answer (score 1):

To have your `contact.enabled` and `contact.memo` updated as expected, try this approach using `@Binding var appData: AppData` and a simple version
of `Contact`.

Working test example code

```
struct AppData : Codable {
    var contacts: [Contact] = []
}

struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable {  // <--- here
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = "New Contact"
    var userModificationDate: Date = Date.distantPast
    var memo: String = "Memo here"
    var enabled: Bool = true
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var appData: AppData  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List() {
                ForEach($appData.contacts) { $contact in
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Name", text: $contact.name)
                        Toggle("Enabled", isOn: $contact.enabled).labelsHidden()
                        TextField("Memo", text: $contact.memo)
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                let contact = Contact(userModificationDate: .now)
                appData.contacts.append(contact)
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
            .padding(20)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var appData = AppData()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestView(appData: $appData)  // <--- here
            Divider()
            List(appData.contacts) { contact in  // <--- for testing
                HStack {
                    Text(contact.name).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text(contact.enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled").foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text(contact.memo).foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```